# Slicing discontinuous data into continuous parts in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have this discontinuous array:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 10, 11, 12]
```

I need it to be an array of continuous arrays:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [7, 8], [10, 11, 12]]
```

I'm looping through the original, comparing each value to the last to build new arrays:

```
parts = []
last = nil
a.each do |n|
  parts.push [] if last.nil? || last+1 != n
  parts.last.push n
  last = n
end
```

It feels dirty and un-Ruby-like. I'm interesting in finding a clean, elegant solution.

Comment: please post what you already tried.

Comment: @Kyle code is pending, but already explained. However, it's irrelevant to the kind of answer I'd like to find.

Comment: it may be relevant. You may already have an elegant solution. We have no way of knowing. You're much more likely to get responses if you provide your current solution.

Comment: @Kyle gotcha... updated now

Comment: "You're much more likely to get responses if you provide your current solution." To expand on that, you're much more likely to avoid getting your question closed by showing your work. One of the reasons for closing questions is failure to do this: "Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself."

Comment: I'm curious, are you assuming the initial array will hold only unique values? How should the output look for `[1, 1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 10, 11, 12]`? Also, should the array be sorted or read as is?

Comment: @rthbound I'd say it's safe to assume they're already sorted and unique.

Comment: My real-life data is in form of `{Time => Float, Time => Float}` generated by a `AVG(reading_value)...GROUP BY created_at` query.

Comment: @theTinMan Noted. Though I'd argue that this question is not about code I've written, but rather to find the best answer to a problem I'm facing. I think it would have been more appropriate to post my current code as an answer. I suppose the reason I didn't is because it's not really a good answer, and I didn't want a downvote.

Comment: There is a different category for questions asking for code, so, either way, you are expected to show your effort, including code you've tried that worked or didn't work. Arguing the point would only get your question closed and downvoted. They really want questions showing effort these days.

Comment: There's a difference between "Why doesn't this work?" and "What is the best way to do this?". The former always requires a code sample while the latter may or may not. If one asks "What's the fastest way to iterate an array?" it doesn't require a code sample. This question is similar to that.

Comment: I think what Tin Man is saying is that you should show some attempt to solve the problem, even if the code doesn't work. You don't want to give the impression that you've come here expecting others to write all the code from scratch and you can just sit back and use it. Think of it as showing respect for others' time, and doing some hurdle-jumping yourself before asking others to. For the "fastest iteration" example: sure you should include what you tried, because it might even benefit those who have used your non-optimal method; good answers can even explain why it's non-optimal.

Comment: +1 @Kelvin, that's exactly the point, and why Stack Overflow has defined the reasons for closing questions they way they have. They expect to see effort, at a minimum showing searches done and why those weren't useful.

Answer (score 2):

Modified version of @hirolau's.

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 10, 11, 12]
prev = a[0] - 1
a.slice_before { |cur|  [prev + 1 != cur, prev = cur][0] }.to_a
# => [[1, 2, 3], [7, 8], [10, 11, 12]]
```

---

```
prev = a[0] - 1
a.slice_before { |cur|
  discontinuous = prev + 1 != cur
  prev = cur
  discontinuous
}.to_a   
# => [[1, 2, 3], [7, 8], [10, 11, 12]]
```

Comment: Also I think naming the previous value "x" is the same story - shorter, but harder to read.

Comment: @tybro0103, I see. Renamed `x` back to `prev`.

Comment: After seeing sawa's answer, I think this is a nice middle ground between short and easy-to-read. Very nice.

Answer (score 2):

```
([a[0]] + a).each_cons(2).slice_before{|k, l| k + 1 != l}.map{|a| a.map(&:last)}
# => [[1, 2, 3], [7, 8], [10, 11, 12]]
```

Comment: `[0]` should be replaced with `[a[0]]`.

Comment: @falsetru Thanks for the idea. I incorporated it. That makes it more generally available.

Comment: This is nice. I did have to double check the docs for each of those methods before I could understand it.

Answer (score 1):

A modified example from the enumerable documentation:

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_before

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 10, 11, 12]
prev = a.first
p a.slice_before { |e|
  prev, prev2 = e, prev
  prev2 + 1 != e
}.to_a # => [[1, 2, 3], [7, 8], [10, 11, 12]]
```

Comment: I'd recommend using braces (`{}`) instead of `do`/`end` with a `slice_before` block, especially one with a trailing `to_a`. Idiomatic Ruby uses braces for blocks that return a value we're chaining to. Technically they're the same but it's a readability, and an adopted coding-style we've come to expect.

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be quite a few ways to do this.

```
a.each_cons(2).each_with_object([[ a.first ]]) do |pair, con_groups| 
  con_groups.push( [] ) if pair.reduce( :-) < -1
  con_groups.last.push( pair.last )
end
```

Comment: Sorry, had to get the smiley in there!

Comment: had to up-vote the smiley :-) (or the use of reduce, hard to say which)

Answer (score 1):

```
arr.slice_before([]) {|elt, state|
  (elt-1 != state.last).tap{ state << elt }
}.to_a
```

Explanation:

`state` is basically a growing copy of `arr`, and is initialized to a copy of the argument passed to `slice_before`. `state.last` represents the previous element. Note that in the first iteration, `state.last` is `nil`, and the comparison still works.

I use `tap` to build `state` but also letting the comparison result get returned. I could've used `begin`/`ensure`, or assigned to a variable, but `tap` is shorter. Order is important here - I can only append *after* doing the comparison.

Another advantage is that I don't have to reference any external variables from inside the block, nor use a modified version of `arr`.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative, not as good as proposed one, but closer to Your own and a bit more readable

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 10, 11, 12]

a.each_with_object({ last: nil, result: [] }) do | n, memo|
  memo[:result] << [] unless memo[:last] && memo[:last] + 1 == n
  memo[:result].last << n
  memo[:last] = n
end[:result]
```

Comment: Probably differences of perception. I don't qualify for an ultimate truth :) I like the first solution better too.

Answer (score 0):

Fun question, tybro0103... here's what I came up with

```
tarr = [1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 10, 11, 12]
out  = []

tarr.count.times do
  i = 0 unless tarr[0].nil? && break

  while tarr[0..i] == (0..i).map {|x| tarr[0] + x }
    i+=1
  end

  out << tarr.shift(i)
end
```